# opentelemetry-rust: Increasing the channel size of batched OtlpTracePipeline

Tags: rust, open-telemetry

Is it possible to increase the channel size of OpenTelemetry span batch processor?
I'm currently getting `OpenTelemetry trace error occurred. cannot send span to the batch span processor because the channel is full` error on a high-traffic scenario.

Here is my configuration code:

```rust
let mut exporter_metadata = MetadataMap::new();
exporter_metadata.insert(
    "api-key",
    "<redacted>".parse()?,
);
let exporter = opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
    .tonic()
    .with_endpoint("https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317")
    .with_tls_config(ClientTlsConfig::default())
    .with_metadata(exporter_metadata);
let trace_config = opentelemetry::sdk::trace::config()
    .with_resource(Resource::new(vec![
        KeyValue::new(
            opentelemetry_semantic_conventions::resource::SERVICE_NAME,
            "worker",
        ),
        KeyValue::new(
            opentelemetry_semantic_conventions::resource::SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
            "dev-instance",
        ),
        KeyValue::new("kind", "server"),
    ]))
    .with_sampler(Sampler::TraceIdRatioBased(1.0));
let tracer = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
    .tracing()
    .with_exporter(exporter)
    .with_trace_config(trace_config)
    .install_batch(opentelemetry::runtime::Tokio)?;
let otel_filter = Targets::new().with_target("worker", LevelFilter::INFO);
let otel_layer = tracing_opentelemetry::layer()
    .with_tracer(tracer)
    .with_filter(otel_filter);
```

I've looked through the documentation, but there was no configuration mentioning the size of the channel.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the source code, I've come up with the following solution:

In `batch_config.rs`, declare new trait and implement it for `OtlpTracePipeline`:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use core::convert::Into;
use core::option::Option;
use core::option::Option::{None, Some};
use core::result::Result::Ok;
use opentelemetry::sdk::trace::{BatchConfig, BatchSpanProcessor, Config, TraceRuntime};
use opentelemetry::trace::{TraceError, TracerProvider};
use opentelemetry::{global, sdk};
use opentelemetry_otlp::{Error, OtlpTracePipeline, SpanExporter, SpanExporterBuilder};

pub trait BatchConfigurable {
    fn install_batch_manual<B, R>(
        self,
        trace_config: Option<Config>,
        exporter_builder: Option<B>,
        batch_config: BatchConfig,
        runtime: R,
    ) -> Result<sdk::trace::Tracer, TraceError>
    where
        B: Into<SpanExporterBuilder>,
        R: TraceRuntime;
}

fn build_batch_with_config_and_exporter<R: TraceRuntime>(
    exporter: SpanExporter,
    batch_config: BatchConfig,
    trace_config: Option<Config>,
    runtime: R,
) -> sdk::trace::Tracer {
    let batch = BatchSpanProcessor::builder(exporter, runtime)
        .with_batch_config(batch_config)
        .build();
    let mut provider_builder = sdk::trace::TracerProvider::builder().with_span_processor(batch);
    if let Some(config) = trace_config {
        provider_builder = provider_builder.with_config(config);
    }
    let provider = provider_builder.build();
    let tracer =
        provider.versioned_tracer("opentelemetry-otlp", Some(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")), None);
    let _ = global::set_tracer_provider(provider);
    tracer
}

impl BatchConfigurable for OtlpTracePipeline {
    fn install_batch_manual<B, R>(
        self,
        trace_config: Option<Config>,
        exporter_builder: Option<B>,
        batch_config: BatchConfig,
        runtime: R,
    ) -> Result<sdk::trace::Tracer, TraceError>
    where
        B: Into<SpanExporterBuilder>,
        R: TraceRuntime,
    {
        let exporter_builder = exporter_builder.map(|b| b.into());
        Ok(build_batch_with_config_and_exporter(
            exporter_builder
                .ok_or(Error::NoExporterBuilder)?
                .build_span_exporter()?,
            batch_config,
            trace_config,
            runtime,
        ))
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```rust
    let batch_config = BatchConfig::default().with_max_queue_size(1048576);
    let tracer = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .install_batch_manual(
            Some(trace_config),
            Some(exporter),
            batch_config,
            opentelemetry::runtime::Tokio,
        )?;
```

Roughly speaking, `install_batch_manual` is equivalent to calling `.with_exporter().with_trace_config().install_batch`, but with customizable BatchConfig option.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTelemetry provides a bunch of environment variables](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/configuration/sdk-environment-variables/) in order to configure this kind of things.

The env var you're looking for is `OTEL_BSP_MAX_QUEUE_SIZE` and its default value is `2048`.
(see the corresponding [Rust code here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust/blob/main/opentelemetry-sdk/src/trace/span_processor.rs#L557C12-L557C35))